# Call a javascript function from one frame's page to another frame's page, gives "Permission Denied" error

Tags: javascript, iframe, frames

I have an page which contains frameset of 2 frames. I am loading http://testhost/test.aspx in frame1 and http://otherhost/test2.aspx in frame2. Now, i want to call the javascript function of test.aspx from test2.aspx using parent and child elements. But I am getting "Permission Denied" error, as both pages are from different domain.

**Please note that test.aspx and test2.aspx are under two different hosts.**

Please help me by suggesting a work around for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly call them, communication is possible if you have control over both test.aspx and test2.aspx.  You can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) from [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html#web-messaging) in supoprted browsers.

It would be much easier to use a library that does this with fallbacks for [browsers that don't support postMessage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging), like [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM/#readme).

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing "same origin policy" issues because pages are on two different domains.

Best "solution" yet.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain